# Netty HTTP/2 Streaming Client?

Tags: netty

I'm writing a Netty HTTP/2 client that sends multipart data in it's body.  One of the parts is an audio stream that comes to me in real time.

Right now I have a handler that takes in the stream (encapsulated in a message object) and have it iterate over the stream pumping data out over the wire.

I think this is a problem because it ties up a handler until the stream is depleted.  In other words, Netty is no longer sending data in an asynchronous manner.

I've seen the example http2 client [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/d771526f8cfe262914ef40f0613e1e4b9e3a3aca/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/client/Http2Client.java). They seem to use FullHttpRequest objects which take byte buffers for the body content.  My question is how do I handle sending an http2 stream without tying up a thread until the stream is empty?